# Does ~/.bashrc set environment for users whose shell is /sbin/nologin?

Tags: profile, umask

I have an SFTP server and have set user shells to nologin to restrict access to SFTP.  I want to set a conditional umask of 0002 so that newly created files are group writable for all SFTP users.  Can I put this code in their bashrc to ensure that all newly created files are group writable or is there a better method?

Red Hat 5/6 Linux.
NFS3 filesystem

Comment: No, bashrc is only relevant if the users are using bash. They're not.

Comment: There are several methods of creating shared directories, see http://www.apaddedcell.com/ssh-allowing-multiple-users-edit-files-and-directories-shared-folders. ACL give finer gain of control, and what I would use on such a shared (ftp) server see http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Comment: Do you know of an ACL that works on Linux when using NFS version 3?  I do not.

Comment: @Terdon, I'll admit this is not one of my finer questions :)

Comment: No worries, bad day huh :)? By the way, bashrc is even less relevant since it is only read for interactive, non login shells so it is not read (by default) when logging in via ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @terdon stated in his comment, `.bashrc` is relevant only for users using `bash`. This is because the file is sourced when `bash` is launched.

To achieve what you want to do, the easiest solution is to add the option `-u` to the line that reads something like

`Subsystem  sftp    /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server`

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. For example :

`Subsystem  sftp    /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server -u 0002`

See `man 8 sftp-server` for details.

Comment: That is great!  I was looking at the man for sshd_config.  I feel silly now!

Comment: For others who are researching this, I should state that many SFTP clients ignore umask if the server permissions are less strict than the file permissions being placed.  I think Filezilla is one of the few that supposedly respects umask, alas I can't delegate what clients are used, therefore I ended up using a cron job to chmod the dirs.